# Kuberenetes Available schedulars

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How would I display available schedulers in my cluster in order to use non default one using the **schedulerName** field?

Any link to a document describing how to "install" and use a custom scheduler is highly appreciated :)

Thx in advance

Comment: you can go through the official doc: [configure-multiple-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) which gives a good overview of the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedulers can be found among your `kube-system` pods. You can then filter the output to your needs with `kube-scheduler` as the search key:

```sh
➜  ~ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-9wfkp                   0/1     Completed   15         264d
coredns-6955765f44-jmz9j                   1/1     Running     16         264d
etcd-acid-fuji                             1/1     Running     17         264d
kube-apiserver-acid-fuji                   1/1     Running     6          36d
kube-controller-manager-acid-fuji          1/1     Running     21         264d
kube-proxy-hs2qb                           1/1     Running     0          177d
kube-scheduler-acid-fuji                   1/1     Running     21         264d
```

You can retrieve the yaml file with:

```sh
➜  ~ kubectl get pods -n kube-system <scheduler pod name> -oyaml
```

If you bootstrapped your cluster with Kubeadm you may also find the yaml files in the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`:

```yaml
➜  manifests sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.17.6
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---------
```

The location for minikube is similar but you do have to login in the minikube's virtual machine first with `minikube ssh`.

For more reading please have a look how to [configure multiple schedulers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) and [how to write custom schedulers.](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-custom-scheduler/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

- `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep scheduler`